# Converting from base X to base Y in JAVA is returning different characters than the same function in PHP

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, byte, radix

I've created a method in JAVA in order to do the same thing of an existing PHP function, that is: convert an arbitrarily large number from any base to any base.

The java method is working fine and I can convert numbers from one base to another and then convert it back, but the resulted strings are different from the PHP function. This is a problem to me, because I want to convert a number in PHP and then convert it back in JAVA.

For example, lets convert the number `998765;43210;9999;2` from Base11 with alphabet `0123456789;` to Base21 with alphabet `0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK` in PHP and JAVA:

Result of the example in PHP:

```
convBase("998765;43210;9999;2", "0123456789;", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK") = "GJK7K6B2KKGKK96"
```

Result of the example in JAVA:

```
convBase("998765;43210;9999;2", "0123456789;", "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK") = "1B0EJAJ0IG3DABI"
```

I would like the results to be the same, so I could convert a number in PHP and convert it back in JAVA.

I think that the problem can be character encoding, but I don't know how to solve it.

**PHP function and test:**

```
<?php
    function convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, $toBaseInput)
    {
        if ($fromBaseInput==$toBaseInput) return $numberInput;
        $fromBase = str_split($fromBaseInput,1);
        $toBase = str_split($toBaseInput,1);
        $number = str_split($numberInput,1);
        $fromLen=strlen($fromBaseInput);
        $toLen=strlen($toBaseInput);
        $numberLen=strlen($numberInput);
        $retval='';
        if ($toBaseInput == '0123456789')
        {
            $retval=0;
            for ($i = 1;$i <= $numberLen; $i++)
                $retval = bcadd($retval, bcmul(array_search($number[$i-1], $fromBase),bcpow($fromLen,$numberLen-$i)));
                return $retval;
        }
        if ($fromBaseInput != '0123456789')
            $base10=convBase($numberInput, $fromBaseInput, '0123456789');
            else
            $base10 = $numberInput;
            if ($base10<strlen($toBaseInput))
                return $toBase[$base10];
                while($base10 != '0')
                {
                    $retval = $toBase[bcmod($base10,$toLen)].$retval;
                    $base10 = bcdiv($base10,$toLen,0);
                    }
                    return $retval;
    }

    header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');

    $number = "998765;43210;9999;2";
    $fromBase = "0123456789;";
    $toBase = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK";

    $converted = convBase($number, $fromBase, $toBase);
    $back = convBase($converted, $toBase, $fromBase);

    echo "Number: ".$number."<br>";
    echo "Converted: ".$converted."<br>";
    echo "Back: ".$back."<br>";
?>
```

**JAVA method and test:**

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class ConvBase{

    public static String convBase(String number, String fromBaseInput, String toBaseInput){

        if (fromBaseInput.equals(toBaseInput))
            return number;

        BigInteger fromLen = new BigInteger(""+fromBaseInput.length());
        BigInteger toLen = new BigInteger(""+toBaseInput.length());
        BigInteger numberLen = new BigInteger(""+number.length());

        if(toBaseInput.equals("0123456789")){
            BigInteger retval = BigInteger.ZERO;
            for(int i=1; i<=number.length(); i++){
                retval = retval.add(
                    new BigInteger(""+fromBaseInput.indexOf(number.charAt(i-1))).multiply(
                        fromLen.pow(numberLen.subtract(new BigInteger(""+i)).intValue())
                        //pow(fromLen, numberLen.subtract(new BigInteger(""+i)))
                    ) 
                );
            }
            return ""+retval;
        }

        String base10 = fromBaseInput.equals("0123456789") ? number : convBase(number, fromBaseInput, "0123456789");

        if(new BigInteger(base10).compareTo(toLen) < 0)
            return ""+toBaseInput.charAt(Integer.parseInt(base10));

        String retVal = "";
        BigInteger base10bigInt = new BigInteger(base10);
        while(!base10bigInt.equals(BigInteger.ZERO)){
            retVal = toBaseInput.charAt(base10bigInt.mod(toLen).intValue()) + retVal;
            base10bigInt = base10bigInt.divide(toLen); 
        }
        return ""+retVal;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String number = "98765;43210;9999;2";
        String fromBase = "0123456789;";
        String toBase = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJK";

        String converted = ConvBase.convBase(number, fromBase, toBase);
        String back = ConvBase.convBase(converted, toBase, fromBase);

        System.out.println("Number = "+number);
        System.out.println("Converted = "+converted);
        System.out.println("Back = "+back); 

        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: I'd start by a) using a much, much smaller number for testing; b) working out which result is correct, so you know which to look at. Also note that Java isn't an acronym, and shouldn't be in all-caps.

Comment: You don't really need to use `BigInteger` for your length variables since you can't have a `String.length` bigger than `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, this would be a bit more readable.

Comment: If I run your code with the value you have provided : I get the same value has your PHP =>  `GJK7K6B2KKGKK96`; same with `new BigInteger("998765A43210A9999A2", 11).toString(21)`  (why do you want to use a different "charset" than what everyone is used to ?) so I would say you have a problem with your test.

Comment: `String number = "98765;43210;9999;2";` ... this is just a typo in your test...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a typo in your test case. Both programs seem to be correct, or at least consistent.

Your Java variant converts "98765;43210;9999;2" while your PHP program converts "998765;43210;9999;2". Note the two nines at the beginning. When I changed the number I got the following output:

```
Number = 998765;43210;9999;2
Converted = GJK7K6B2KKGKK96
Back = 998765;43210;9999;2
```

which is consistent with the output of the PHP version.

Comment: You are correct. I am ashamed! Sorry guys for taking your time.